# How To Compare Image Data Types In SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I'm having a lot of trouble writing a select statement to compare two values in t-sql which are of type image.  This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT a.UserId, b.UserId
FROM [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] as a inner join [dbo].[aspnet_Profile] as b on
    (a.UserId = <some string> AND b.UserId = <some other string>)
WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(a.PropertyValuesBinary) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(b.PropertyValuesBinary)
```

But I keep getting error messages no matter what I do to the WHERE clause.  For the above query, the error message I get is:

> Error in binarychecksum. There are no
>   comparable columns in the
>   binarychecksum input.

At any rate, any help would be very much appreciated.  I'm have a very hard time doing anything with this data-type, for some reason...

BTW:  I'm using SQL Server Web (I think it's the 2008 edition)...

Thanks!

Andrew

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `binarychecksum` on image types

> BINARY_CHECKSUM ignores columns of
>   noncomparable data types in its
>   computation. Noncomparable data types
>   include text, ntext, image, cursor,
>   xml, and noncomparable common language
>   runtime (CLR) user-defined types.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173784.aspx

It might be easier to store a MD5 has along with the image. I can't imagine that you're getting good performance by requesting a binary_checksum of all of your images!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Adam.  I'm using Sql Server Management Studio, and I just wanted to compare two values in a table.  It's a one-off calculation, and itsn't really part of any code.  Is there any way to do this in t-sql, without downloading any external implementations of MD5?  Does t-sql implement MD5?  I'm not really a DBA or anything...

Answer (score 0):

Can you do this?

```
   select BINARY_CHECKSUM(A.PropertyValuesBinary) from aspnet_Profile as A
```

Knowing the #s of the error messages would help us help you.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the idea.  The error message I get with the above select statement is:

Comment: Msg 8184, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Error in binarychecksum. There are no comparable columns in the binarychecksum input.